# Calculate expected number of round we reach to $n$.

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Suppose $x=2$ now each round we set $x=x^2$ or $x=x^3$  with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ until we
> reach given number $n$,how we can calculate expected number of round
> to reach $n$?

I think if each iteration  we set  $x=x^2$ at step $x^{2^k}\geq n$ we reach $n$ from this $k=log logn$ ,but i want to calculate in expected.The answer is $\theta(loglogn)$,but i'm confused how we reach this.

Comment: do you mean $x_k = x_{k-1}^2 \textrm{ or } x_{k-1}^3$?

Comment: Yes, it's ture.

Comment: In each iteration, do you set $x$ as $x^2$ or $x^3$ randomly?

Comment: yes we set x randomly

Comment: So I guess we are only considering target values that are powers of 2 ? So clearly we cannot reach for example $n=11$, right?

Comment: We can continue until we get $x\geq n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets draw a tree of possible outcome, where each $k^{th}$-level corresponds to all equally likely possible outcomes at the $k^{th}$ round. The top node is zeroth round. Below I draw this tree till 2 rounds.
$$x$$
$$x^2  \quad  x^3$$
$$x^4  \quad  x^6 \quad x^6 \quad x^9$$
Notice that each path from the top node to a leaf corresponds to a complete outcome, where each step is a choice between $x^2$ and $x^3$. And for $k$ levels there are $\sum_{k_1+k_2 = k}\binom{k}{k_1,k_2} = 2^k$ such paths. Where $k_1$ is the number of times $x^2$ was chosen and $k_2$ is the number of times $x^3$ was chosen. A path which has $x^2$ chosen $k_1$ times and $x^3$ chosen $k_3$ times will end at $x^{2^{k_1}\times3^{k_2}}$. Therefore the expectation value after $k$ levels is :
$$E[x_k] = \frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{k_1+k_2=k}\binom{k}{k_1,k_2}x^{2^{k_1} \times3^{k_2}}$$

---

I dont have much experience with big-$O$ estimations, but given the answer my guess would be the following :
Asymptotically only the  $x^{2^{k_1}\times 2^{k_2}}$ term is going to matter (summation is going to add as only exponential in $k$ factors (upper bound on $\binom{k}{k_1}$ is $(\frac{ek}{k_1})^{k_1} )$;the denominator does not matter as $x^{2^{k_1}\times 2^{k_2}}$ is exponential even w.r.t denominator), so we can take the asymptotic term to be $x^{3^{k}}$ . Now if
$$n \approx x^{3^{k}}$$
then,
$$\log n \approx 3^{k}  $$
$$\log \log n \approx k  $$

So my key observations here are:

1. $x^{2^{k_1}\times 2^{k_2}}$ is exponential w.r.t denominator.
2. Anything that we get from summation and multiplication with binomial coefficients is at best exponential in $k$, hence the only thing that matters is $x^{3^{k}}$ as it is double exponential.

Comment: Now,main question is,how we can relate $k$ with $n$?

Comment: Or can you relate $E[x_k]$ to $n$ and clarify in terms of $n$?

Comment: Pick that value of $k$ when $E[x_k]$ is greater than $n$, I am not sure what more can be done ! i.e $k:E[x_k] \geq n$

Comment: have idea to express in asymptotic manner the value of $k$?

Comment: The answer is $\theta(loglogn)$,but i'm confused how we reach this.

Comment: What is $\theta$ or you mean $O(\log\log n)$?

Comment: Answer is  in term of $\theta$ but we can relax and consider as $O(log logn)$